# No puedo publicar actualización de aplicación en Google Play (An unexpected error has occurred)

Tags: android, google-play

Cuando trato de publicar una actualización de mi aplicación en Google Play me lanza el siguiente error:

An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (5BC693A5) (5AFA3126)

Llevo varios días intentando y sigue lanzando ese mensaje. No es un problema de mi APK y es la primera vez que veo un error de este tipo. No he encontrado información respecto a este error en ninguna parte. Me han recomendado que vuelva a generar el APK, que pruebe desde otro navegador, que elimine las cookies del navegador antes de publicar, etc. Pero nada funciona.

[image: Error que muestra la consola]

Comment: Agrega más información, es un update o nueva aplicación?, que paquete tiene tu aplicación actualmente, lo cambiaste? Revisaste que más mensajes se muestran en la consola?

Comment: Es una actualización, simplemente se arreglaron unos errores. No se modificó nada  importante ni la paquetería.

Comment: tendrás el build.gradle antes de la modificación y el nuevo?

Comment: El único cambio en el build.gradle es el versionCode y el versionName

Comment: ok, el versionCode es mayor a la anterior versión ? debe ser un valor entero mayor al anterior. Trata en otro browser por favor!

Comment: No sé explicar cuál era el error. Me crearon un nuevo usuario de Google Play y con ese si pude realizar la publicación. Gracias por la ayuda.